# How to use jest with typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have pretty straightforward question: "How to configure typescript with jest". I know that there are plenty resources for this. But no one solution worked for me.

Here is my `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    roots: [
        '<rootDir>'
    ],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest"
    },
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/tests/**/*.ts'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js'],
    modulePaths: [
        '<rootDir>/src/js/'
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        'Services(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/js/$1'
    },
};
```

First problem is that module name mapper does not work. I added both `modulePaths` and `moduleNameMapper` but no one works. It just simple says: "Can not find module ...".

Another problem is that when I fake module name mapper (for example `'i': '<rootDir>/src/js/State.ts'` and make it work, I have " Unexpected token export". But I followed this guide https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/testing/jest.html and I have the same code as on that example. I tried using babel for jest - the same.

Of course, I tried googling. But no success. I tried different ways - no result.
I spent almost 2 hours on it. I know that there should be a simple solution for this as jest and typescript are popular packages.

**Update**:
Here is my tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information you provided, I would guess that the problem is twofold:

1. Adjust the `moduleNameMapper` regex
2. `Unexpected token export` might indicate a wrong `tsconfig.json` configuration (e.g. `module`)

1.) Wrap `'Services(.*)'` with [regex boundaries](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) `^$`, resulting in `'^Services(.*)$'`. Otherwise it can cause weird errors, as *all* matching sub-strings of the module name are replaced. 
Also I am not sure, if you are rather meaning `'^Services/(.*)$'` (including "/")? As your dummy replacement alias changes the error type, your config seems to have an incorrect regex match, but works in other regards.

2.) Node cannot understand ES module syntax without special flags. Your error indicates, there is probably a transpile step from `import/export` to CommonJS `require` missing. Check your `module` property in `tsconfig.json`/ your test config, if it is set to `"CommonJS"`. Consider the [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) value which depends on `target` property: `target === "ES3" or "ES5" ? "CommonJS" : "ES6"`.

#### Update:

If you use `baseUrl` and `paths` alias configuration in `tsconfig.json`, make sure to also setup [moduleNameMapper](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/#paths-mapping) in jest config. This is a bit redundant, so `ts-jest` offers a [helper](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/#jest-config-with-helper) to extract the values from TS config. You can have a look at [this example](https://github.com/ford04/jest-typescript-sample).

Hope, that gets your problem solved, otherwise a complete code example would be helpful.

Comment: I added my tsconfig.js file content. Also I tried to set "module" key to a dummy string like "dfsfd" and when I ran jest it did not give my any error. Looks like I have wrong "transform" value in jest.config.js.

Comment: I tried to change moduleNameMapper to `'^Services/(.*)$'` - no result. I event tried `'^Services/i$'` and used `import a from Services/i` - no result, it gives `Cannot find module 'Services/i'`. I really can not get a clue what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "when I ran jest it did not give my any error" - that means, it works when you leave out `module` property or set a dummy value? As a last guess, I see by your config you also use react - do you use [css modules imports](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack), which could trigger unexpected token errors, if not mocked out in jest? I would need a minimal sample here to see better what's going on...

Comment: Finally got a solution. Path mapping should have been setup in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: No, `react` is there as a result of copying.

Comment: However, I wonder why it is said everywhere that I can use `jest.config.js` and setup path mapping there.

Comment: If you use `paths` mapping with TS, you also need to configure `moduleNameMapper` in ts-jest. Have a look at the [ts-jext docs](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/#paths-mapping).

Comment: It is not true. I have `paths` only in TS and have no `moduleNameMapper` in jest file. And it works

Comment: You can an answer with your link. It helped me.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks! Let's clear the issue up briefly and out of curiosity - I think the docs are correct here / could not reproduce your case. Look at the sample repo [here](https://github.com/ford04/jest-typescript-sample). `npm run build` runs tsc compiler, `npm test` triggers `jest` - both run successfully. Now, when you comment out the `moduleNameMapper` in jest config, you should get a jest error, but be able to compile with TS. Does your case look similarly?

Comment: Strange, but now it does not work without `moduleNameMapper`. I got it back and it works very fine

Comment: Updated my answer. If you find out something contradictory, let me know (I thing we should use the chat for further conversation ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199531/discussion-between-ford04-and-freelightman).